# PHP - How to wait for disk to be written after commit is called?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, commit, disk

I'm using postgresql. I have to call a jar file that does some operations after db read, within a php script.

$connection is a PDO. I have noticed the following behavoiurs:

Scenario 1:

```
$connection->commit();

exec_shell(java -jar jarname) //it does not give expected behaviour
```

Scenario 2:

```
$connection->commit();

sleep(60);

exec_shell(java -jar jarname) //it does give expected behaviour
```

So, the question is: how to wait until commit writes all data to disk before going on with instructions?

fsync is on in postgres.conf
synchronous_commit is on in postgres.conf

Comment: You could see if the file is locked by another processes. You could have a while loop looking at the last modified date of the file. You could scan the file for a end of file marker.

Comment: @Scuzzy doesn't seem to be the lock on the java file that's the issue here, but PDO::commit not having written all data to table before the java file is being run. If I understand the OP correct.

Comment: Maybe you should mod your java prog to [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with PDO but if you can check the result of a commit you can 
try something like this:

```
$commit_status = $connection->commit();
if($commit_status === TRUE)
{
  exec_shell(java -jar jarname)
}
```

As long as you dont have response from commit status exec_shell wont be called

Comment: $connection->commit(); gives 1 and then execs jar with same problems

Comment: that function returns 1 very quickly